# how to use constructor injection with abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have been trying to learn dependency injection but I have 2 errors when I run my code:

1. `DependencyInjection.Message.Sms()` must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial.
2. Cannot implicitly convert type `DependencyInjection.IInterface` to  `DependencyInjection.MyClass`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Is the code below a good design for DI?

```
namespace DependencyInjection
{
    public interface IInterface
    {

    }

    public abstract class Message
    {
        public virtual void Sms();
    }

    public class MyClass : Message, IInterface
    {
        public override void Sms()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sms gönder.");
        }
    }

    public class ClassManager
    {
        private IInterface _myinterface;


        public MyClass Xyz
        {
            get { return _myinterface; }
            set { _myinterface = value; }
        }

        public ClassManager(IInterface myinterface)
        {
            _myinterface = myinterface;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn Dependency Injection, or just learning to write C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) DependencyInjection.Message.Sms()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Add `abstract` keyword (and remove virtual) to method declaration:

```
public abstract void Sms();
```

> 2) Cannot implicitly convert type 'DependencyInjection.IInterface' to 'DependencyInjection.MyClass'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
private IInterface _myinterface;
public MyClass Xyz
{
    get { return _myinterface; }
    set { _myinterface = value; }
}
```

`Xyz` has return-type of type `MyClass` but in `get` you are returning `_myinterface` which is of type `IInterface`.

Change to following:

```
public IInterface Xyz
{
    get { return _myinterface; }
    set { _myinterface = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public abstract class Message
{
    public virtual void Sms();
}
```

to this

```
public abstract class Message
{
    public abstract void Sms();
}
```

You either give the virtual method a body, like so

```
public virtual void Sms() { }
```

or you mark it as abstract

```
public abstract void Sms();
```

EDIT:

Forgot about the second error. Change this

```
public MyClass Xyz
    {
        get { return _myinterface; }
        set { _myinterface = value; }
    }
```

to this

```
public IInterface Xyz
    {
        get { return _myinterface; }
        set { _myinterface = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Sorry about that :)

Comment: i can use that :  public ClassManager(IInterface myinterface) :  ClassManager mngr = new ClassManager( new MyClass());  BUT I CAN NOT :public MyClass Xyz
    {
        get { return _myinterface; }
        set { _myinterface = value; }
    }

Comment: As I said: change the property type of Xyz from MyClass to IInterface

Answer (score 0):

1. You're declaring a virtual method with no body. Virtual methods must declare a body that will act as the default implementation of the method. You can either declare your method as `abstract`, which means that the derived classes have to provide their own implementation:

   ```
   public abstract void Sms();
   ```

   or you can keep the method virtual and provide a default implementation in the base class:

   ```
   public virtual void Sms()
   {
       // Default or no implementation goes here.
   }
   ```
2. In the following code you're trying to cast `IInterface` to `MyClass`, which is probably not what you want.

   ```
   public MyClass Xyz
   {
       get { return _myinterface; }
       set { _myinterface = value; }
   }
   ```

   you're probably looking to return `IInterface` instead:

   ```
   public IInterface Xyz
   {
       get { return _myinterface; }
       set { _myinterface = value; }
   }
   ```